# Why is the Ariane 5 shorter than the Ariane 4?

Tags: design, ariane

Looking at below image, which compares heights of rockets, I couldn’t help but notice that the Ariane 5 was a short and fat rocket compared to the Ariane 4 (tall and thin). Why would this be advantageous for the Ariane 5?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Fuel changes.

Ariane 5 core burns LOX and Liquid Hydrogen.  This needs larger tanks and thus is wider.

Ariane 4 uses hypergolics that are much denser. (Nitrogen Tetroxide, UMDH).  Thus the tanks are smaller.

(Consider Delta IV using LOX/LH at 5 meters width vs the Atlas V using Kerosene and LOX narrower around 3m.  But about similar performance ranges).

Comment: "This needs larger tanks and thus is wider." Why not make the tanks taller at the same diameter?

Answer (score 0):

Because the Ariane 5 boosters are considerable bigger. The weight of the Ariane 4 ranges from [240-320 tonnes](https://www.esa.int/Enabling_Support/Space_Transportation/Ariane_42). The weight of Ariane 5's boosters is [270 tonnes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ariane_5) each for a total of 540 tonnes. The total weight being 850 tonnes, this is a large portion. Therefore, Ariane 5 isn't as tall because, well, it has the majority of its mass stored on the side in the boosters. On [Ariane 4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ariane_4) the boosters never take more than a 1/5 of the mass. Also Ariane 4 had launch configurations with out boosters, Ariane 5 would never lift off the ground without them.